# Parsing txt file in java and returning a boolean

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

Im trying to parse a txt file thats set up like this

```
HBR - [false, true, false, true]
CKR - [false, false, false, true]
GFT - [true, true, false, true]
```

I want to loop through each line and return a boolean of true or false.
This boolean is whether or not the 3 letter identifier exists in said txt file.
This is what I got so far, Ive been lost for days

```
public boolean bDoesLineExist() throws IOException {
    String file = "C:\\Parse\\alarmmasksettings.txt";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8"));
    try {
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            String[] fields = line.split("-");
            if (fields[0].equals("HBR")) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try debugging and check `fields` elements - the split is probably leaving trailing white space so the comparison fails.

Comment: Its not that, its still asking for a return

Comment: What does _still asking for a return_ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that you just want to determine if a specific ***identifier*** is contained within the data file you want to read but I should think that at some point you may want to obtain the boolean settings for that specific ***identifier***.

You can kill two birds with one stone (so to speak) by creating a method to retrieve the the boolean settings for a specific identifier and if the ***identifier*** can't be found in file then **null** boolean array is returned. If however the ***identifier*** is found in file then a boolean array of the settings is returned. Perhaps a method something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a boolean array containing the boolean settings for the supplied 
 * field name.<br>
 * 
 * @param settingsFor (String) The desired field name to get settings for.
 * 
 * @return (Boolean Array) Returns a boolean array containing the boolean 
 * settings for the supplied field name. Returns null is the field name is 
 * not found in file.
 */
public static boolean[] getMaskSettings(String settingsFor) {
    // Boolean Array to hold a specific field's boolean settings.
    boolean[] sets = null;  
    
    // 'Try With Resourses' used to to auto-close the reader.
    try (java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(
                new java.io.FileInputStream("alarmmasksettings.txt"), "UTF-8"))) {
        
        String line;
        // Read each file line until the End Of File (EOF)...
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Skip blank lines.
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            /* Split the currently read in file line into two spaecific
               parts, the field Name and the boolean Settings for that
               field.
            */
            
            String[] lineParts = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("\\s{0,}\\-\\s{0,}");
            
            /* The first array element of lineParts[] should hold the field Name:
               Is the field name what was supplied (not case sensitive).  */
            if (lineParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(settingsFor)) {
                // Yes it is...Split the second lineParts[] array element which
                // should be holding the boolean settings for the supplied field, 
                // into a String Array...
                String[] settingsStringArray = lineParts[1].split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
                
                // Initialize the sets[] boolean array declared at the beginning of this method.
                sets = new boolean[settingsStringArray.length];
                
                /* Iterate through the settingsStringArray[] String array
                   and convert and apply the string representations of "true"
                   or "false" settings to their actual boolean value and 
                   apply them to the proper index in the sets[] boolean array. */
                for (int i = 0; i < settingsStringArray.length; i++) {
                    sets[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(settingsStringArray[i]);
                }
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    
    /* Since the sets[] boolean array was initially declared as null
       and if the desired field name was NOT found in file then the 
       sets[] arrays is never initialized and therefore is null and 
       this is what will be returned. If however the desired field 
       name was found in file then the sets[] array is initialized 
       and filled accordingly. 
    */
    return sets;
}
```

**How you might use this method:**

```
String fieldName = "HBR";
boolean[] settings = getMaskSettings(fieldName);
if (settings == null) {
    System.out.println("The field name \"" + fieldName + "\" is not in file!");
}
else {
    System.out.print("Settings for the field name (" + fieldName + ") are: --> ");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(settings).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
if (fields[0].startsWith("HBR")) {
```

instead of

```
 if (fields[0].equals("HBR")) {
```

or may be try -

```
 if (fields[0].trim().equals("HBR")) {
```

as you would have space in the tokenized string